# How to find C# Assembly Project References in other Projects within Solution using Resharper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I'm troubleshooting code in a C# .Net Data Access Class Library (i.e.Assembly) that my Team wrote. Let's call this project `DAL.csproj`. This project is inside a very large Visual Studio 2012 solution (50+ projects) consisting of several WCF services, a proxy service library that proxies calls between various WCF services, a Winforms application and a whole bunch of other C# Projects.

I need to find out in what other C# Projects the `DAL.csproj` project is referenced in (i.e. has been added as a Project reference), using Visual Studio or Resharper. (I'm guessing this feature is not built in inside Visual Studio 2012, hence I am trying with Resharper).

I tried right clicking the `DAL.csproj` project inside Visual Studio, and did not find any context menu to find Usages / References i.e. where all this `DAL.csproj` is referenced in.

Just to be clear, I need to find out which other C# Projects inside my solution have added a Project reference to the `DAL.csproj` Project in the same solution.

Versions of software: Visual Studio 2012 SP4. Resharper 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Right click on `References` folder and select `Optimize References`. You will see what code is dependent on it.

Comment: Thanks @gleng. This is showing me all the assemblies **referenced in** my Data Access Class Library. I want to go the other way round, i.e. to see all the projects that **are referencing** my Data Access Class Library. Makes sense? +1 because you introduced me to this new feature I did not know about :)

Comment: @Shiva Doh. That's the only way I know about doing it. Other than individually clicking each project and doing it one by one.

Answer (score 0):

The [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) tool can draw you a diagram of assembly dependencies, if that's an option for you. R# won't help you much in that specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two ways in VS 2012 itself:

1 - right-click your solution in the solution explorer and select 'Project Dependencies'
2 - Select Architecture > Generate Dependency Graph from the file menu. (This might be a premium / ultimate feature)